# Adding evolution lines to a stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I would like to add lines on my stacked barplot in order to bring out the evolution group by group. Currently, I found an alternative solution with the ggpubr package.

Any help will be appreciate ! Thanks !

```
# My dataset     
dff
#    day composition median
# 1   JO           a  12.21
# 2   JO           b   0.79
# 3   JO           c  42.06
# 4   JO           d  30.65
# 5   JO           e   0.00
# 6  J28           a   1.28
# 7  J28           b   0.38
# 8  J28           c  85.13
# 9  J28           d   7.90
# 10 J28           e   0.00

# Stacked barplot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dff) +   
  geom_col(aes(x = day, y = median, fill = composition)) + 
  ylim(0,100)
```

[image]

```
# Median linked by lines
library(ggpubr)
ggpaired(data = dff,x = "day", y = "median", color = "composition",
 line.color = "gray", line.size = 0.4, xlab = FALSE, ylab = "Median")
```

[image]

## Desired solution (or something like that)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
w = 0.9 # this is the width of geom_col; in case you want something other than the default width

ggplot(data = dff,
       aes(x = day, y = median, fill = composition)) +   
  geom_col(width = w) +
  geom_line(aes(x = ifelse(as.integer(day) == 1, 
                           as.integer(day) + w/2,
                           as.integer(day) - w/2)),
            position = "stack")
```

[image: plot]

Data:

```
dff <- read.table(text = "    day composition median
1   JO           a  12.21
2   JO           b   0.79
3   JO           c  42.06
4   JO           d  30.65
5   JO           e   0.00
6  J28           a   1.28
7  J28           b   0.38
8  J28           c  85.13
9  J28           d   7.90
10 J28           e   0.00")
```